# bash variable in curl command

Tags: bash, variables, curl

In below example (which I got it from PagerDuty webpage):

`machine="hi"
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST \

    -d "{ \"service_key\": \"e93facc04764012d7bfb002500d5d1a6\", \"description\": \"FAILURE for production/HTTP on machine $machine\" }" \

                                                                         "https://events.pagerduty.com/generic/2010-04-15/create_event.json"`

I want to use variables in description like:

```
  "description": "FAILURE for $machine",
```

However it does not work and it only shows me the `"FAILURE for $machine",`
I tried `"FAILURE for ${machine}",` but it does not work too. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: This question makes no sense.  You should not edit the question to eliminate the need for an answer.  Please revert to version 2; the edit in version 3 is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that use use single quotes. You need to use double quotes and escape and double quote in the string:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST \
-d "{    
  \"service_key\": \"e93facc04764012d7bfb002500d5d1a6\",
  ...
  \"description\": \"FAILURE for production/HTTP on machine $machine\"
}" \
"https://events.pagerduty.com/generic/2010-04-15/create_event.json"
```

Quite tedious, but it will do the job.

Comment: Thanks Why doing this for service key?

Comment: Just to show an example. You need to escape ANY " in the text if using double quotes for the string.

Comment: It doesnot work it shows me {"status":"unrecognized object","message":"Event object format is unrecognized","errors":["JSON parse error"]}T

Comment: Sorry, forgot to escape one of the quotes.

Comment: You can check what JSON is used exactly by using echo: `echo "{    
  \"service_key\": \"e93facc04764012d7bfb002500d5d1a6\",
  \"description\": \"FAILURE for production/HTTP on machine $machine\",
}"`, then you could validate that JSON

Comment: There also was an extra comma after the `$machine` containing line

Comment: Note that the ... is a placeholder for all the other lines

Comment: I confirm that if removing the ... and setting `$machine` to `foo` and printing it with `echo`, I can successfully validate the output on http://jsonlint.com/, command:`echo "{           
  \"service_key\": \"e93facc04764012d7bfb002500d5d1a6\",
  \"description\": \"FAILURE for production/HTTP on machine $machine\"
}"`

Comment: yes but having `"https://events.pagerduty.com/generic/2010-04-15/create_event.json"
` it does not work

Comment: Could you post the command that currently doesnt work for you? I'm not entirely sure what exactly doesnt work for you at the moment to be honest. Where do you have the URL specified in the last comment?

Comment: @sweet Im still not entirely sure what's the current issue, but I added the URL (https://events.pagerduty.com/generic/2010-04-15/create_event.json) to my partial example, to show a little bit more complete example.

Comment: If I copy&paste exactly the code that is currently listed first in your post into my shell, it shows me a correct output (curl fetches the page): `{"status":"invalid event","message":"Event object is invalid","errors":["event_type is missing or blank"]}`

Comment: Yes I get same with `Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string – sweet 3 mins ago  edit ` If it is successful it should show status:"successful"

Comment: Could you post the full command you're using somewhere? I'm currently unable to reproduce your issue. Generally, that means youre either missing a backslash at the end of a line or you (more probably) forgot to escape one of the double quotes!

Comment: you mean \+escape+"service_key??

Comment: You just need backslashes before each newline. Escaping a `"` means writing `\"`

Comment: I am exactly doing this
 "->\"  in all the places having "

Comment: Could you post the *full* command that leads to the error somewhere? Else Im unable to help you, because I cant reproduce it!

Comment: How do you copy&paste this into your shell? I assume the issue arises somewhere on the way, because  if I select it and middle-mouse-click into my Ubuntu zsh, everything works as intended, the request is made correctly.

Comment: Oh That was my problem editing in notepad++. Thanks a lot for your help